# Why is my method that changes gizmo color preventing the gizmo from being drawn?

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, editor

As I noted in comments in the following code block, checkGizmoColor() prevents the gizmo from appearing in the editor window. I double checked, and checkGizmoColor() does change the gizmo color succesfully. However, if i change the gizmo color with Gizmos.color = Color.red; inside of OnDrawGizmos() the gizmo is drawn with no issue.

I do not see how these to ways of selecting gizmo color should have such different results.

```
private void OnDrawGizmos() {

    checkGizmoColor ();
    //for some reason, checkGizmoColor changes the color succesfully
    //but then the gizmo is not drawn
    //However, if i set Gizmos.color to red, the gizmo IS drawn

    Gizmos.color = Color.red;

    Gizmos.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(transform.position, transform.rotation, transform.localScale);

    if (useSphere) {
        Gizmos.DrawSphere (Vector3.zero, radius);
    } else {
        Gizmos.DrawCube(Vector3.zero, new Vector3(hitboxSize.x * 2, hitboxSize.y * 2, hitboxSize.z * 2)); // Because size is halfExtents
    }
}

private void checkGizmoColor() {
    switch (_state) {

    case ColliderState.Closed:
        Gizmos.color = inactiveColor;
        break;
    case ColliderState.Open:
        Gizmos.color = collisionOpenColor;
        break;
    case ColliderState.Colliding;
        Gizmos.color = collidingColor;
        break;
    default;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the content inativeColor,collisionOpenColor,collidingColor.
And check _state in checkGizmoColor().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well because `Color.red` has alpha value = 1 while your colors `inactiveColor`, `collisionOpenColor`, `collidingColor` all have alpha = 0.

I assume you make them as properties which can be edited by editor via inspector by default those colors have alpha values = 0 (like in the picture below) which is why your gizmos become invisible

[image]

Simply set the alpha value (A) to 255 in your inspector or in the code set those colors' `a` property = 1 (Ex: `inactiveColor.a = 1`) then your gizmos will be visible